# Is there a way to iterate over specific month or week

Tags: date, go

Is there a way, in `go`, to iterate over a specific month and get all `time.Date` objects from it?

For instance iterate over April will result in `04012016` until `04312016`:

```
for _, dayInMonth := range date.April {
   // do stuff with dates returned
}
```

*(Currently the above code will not work obviously).*

Or if not part of the standard library is there a third party library that equivalent to [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: Here's a date package that may be useful for this: https://github.com/aodin/date

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no time.Date object defined in the standard library. Only time.Time object. There's also no way to range loop them, but looping them manually is quite simple:

```
// set the starting date (in any way you wish)
start, err := time.Parse("2006-1-2", "2016-4-1")
// handle error

// set d to starting date and keep adding 1 day to it as long as month doesn't change
for d := start; d.Month() == start.Month(); d = d.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
    // do stuff with d
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good solution for me! Just note that the third part of the for loop should have an assignment to d - d = d.AddDate(0, 0, 1).
Unless you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Close but that won't do it. `First Parse()` returns two values, so you need to minimally do `start, _ := time.Parse("2006-1-2", "2016-4-1")` and obviously in reality you usually would want to handle and not discard an error. Second `AddDate()` returns a time.Time, so to use it to increment the value of d you should write `for d := start; d.Month() == start.Month(); d = d.AddDate(0, 0, 1)`

Comment: You're right of course. I should be more careful. Anyways I edited the answer so it works now.

Comment: @jussius What should I do i have a start date and the end date and i Want to find the only monday between them can you help me? If yes can you see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342293/using-golang-how-i-will-print-the-specific-days-mentioned-bettwen-the-range-of-t)

Answer (score 0):

@jessius way can only work if the iteration is within a month.
Better way to iterate is to use epoch format of the time.

for example, for oneDay we know it is 86400 seconds.
we can do follwing

```
oneDay := int64(86400) // a day in seconds.
startDate := int64(1519862400)
endDate := int64(1520640000)

for timestamp := startDate; timestamp <= endDate; timestamp += oneDay {
   // do your work
}
```

Simple and workable for iterating days.

For month, this way cannot work, because each month has different days. I only have similar ideas as @jussius, but tweak to apply to month iteration.

Comment: endDate can be a time greater than the last addition of timestamp += oneDay, thus skipping the last day

Comment: @LorenzoBelli yes, need to be careful of the endDate, might need to process it first to make sure the last day is not skipped.

Answer (score -1):

I'm keen to compare the dates

```
func LeqDates(a, b time.Time) bool {
    year1, month1, day1 := a.Date()
    year2, month2, day2 := b.Date()

    if year1 < year2 {
        return true
    } else if year1 <= year2 && month1 < month2 {
        return true
    } else {
        return year1 <= year2 && month1 <= month2 && day1 <= day2
    }
}
```